# Read from xml to string list C#

Tags: c#

I have these XML file:

```
<cteProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="1.04" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CTe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte">
        <infCte versao="1.04" Id="CTexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
            <ide>
                <compl>
                    <emit>
                        <rem>
                            <CNPJ>11111111111</CNPJ>
                            <IE>2222222</IE>
                            <xNome>Teste</xNome>
                            <enderReme>
                                <xLgr>xxxxxxx xxxxxx</xLgr>
                                <nro>S/N</nro>
                                <xCpl>AREA C</xCpl>
                                <xBairro>PARQ. xxxxxx</xBairro>
                                <cMun>125455</cMun>
                                <xMun>xxxxxx</xMun>
                                <CEP>548848</CEP>
                                <UF>AA</UF>
                                <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
                            </enderReme>
                            <infNFe>
                                **<chave>1</chave>**
                                **<chave>2</chave>**
                                **<chave>3</chave>**
                            </infNFe>
                        </rem>
                        <exped>
                            <CNPJ>2342342342342</CNPJ>
                            <IE>15342683242345480</IE>
                                ...........................
```

And I need to get  values and put inside a string

I try to do this:

```
var ListaChave = new List<string>();

var lista = (from c in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "/rem/chave") select c.Value).ToList();

foreach (string s in lista)
  {
    add the values.....
  }
```

But the s var is null. I don´t know how to get these values. Anybody can help me please!?

Comment: What value has `ns` variable when you call `Descendants()` method?

Comment: Change your `Descendants` portion to `Descendants(ns + "/rem/infNFe/chave")`.  The chave element is a child of theinfNFe element.

Answer (score 3):

Use linq to xml

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

XNamespace ns = @"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte";

List<string> strList = doc.Descendants(ns+"rem").Descendants(ns+"chave").Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
```

and alternatively, you can have more control by doing things like

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an element in the path you passed to `Descendants`.  In your XML document the chave elements are children of infNFe.  Your LINQ query is looking for chave elements under "rem", and not finding any, hence the null result.

Change your query to this:

```
var lista = (from c in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "/rem/infNFe/chave") 
             select c.Value).ToList();
```

And you should get what you're looking for, as long as the ns is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code by just adding the infNFe:

```
var ListaChave = new List<string>();

var lista = (from c in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "/rem/infNFe/chave") 
             select c.Value).ToList();

foreach (string s in lista)
{
   add the values.....
}
```